# force asp.net assert to throw an exception?

Tags: asp.net, assert

My asserts aren't generating message boxes, sometimes they send a message to debug output and end the thread without giving me a more aggressive notification.  How can I force all my Debug.Asserts to just throw, so I know that I see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created our own asserts that throw.

Answer (score 0):

It should throw if you haven't disabled it using `<assert assertuienabled="false"/>` in `<system.diagnostics>` section.